# PLS-00302: component 'GETDATACROSSSELLING' must be declared

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I created a procedure:

```
 PROCEDURE GetDataCrossSelling (
     p_branchcode    IN     MST_BRANCH.BRANCH_ID%TYPE,
     p_result           OUT DATA_CURSOR
   )
   IS
   BEGIN
      OPEN p_result FOR
        SELECT
    STNK.NO_PENGAJUAN NoPengajuan,
    STNK.DO_ID DoNo,
    A.ATTRIBUTE2  stnkName,
    CUST.CUST_NAME  CustomerName,
    STNK.PRG_TAX  ProgressiveTax,
    STNK.BIAYA_LAIN_LAIN BiayaLainLain,
    STNK.BPKB_NO BPKBNo,
    STNK.STNK_NO  STNKno,
    STNK.POLICE_NO  PoliceNo,
    --STNK.NOTICE,
    STNK.STATUS_UPLOAD  statusupload,
    STNK.MESSAGE_UPLOAD  messageupload,
    STNK.UPLOAD_STNK_DATE  tglupload
FROM
    trx_sales_order  A
    LEFT JOIN trx_delivery_order  B ON A.so_id = B.so_id
    LEFT JOIN trx_stnk  STNK ON B.DO_ID = STNK.DO_ID
    LEFT JOIN mst_branch_finance_company  C ON A.branch_finance_id = C.branch_finance_id
    LEFT JOIN mst_customer  CUST ON A.CUST_ID = CUST.CUST_ID
    LEFT JOIN trx_pengajuan_bbnstnk Peng ON PENG.NO_PENGAJUAN = STNK.NO_PENGAJUAN
    LEFT JOIN mst_storage_detail stor ON STOR.STOCK_ID = STNK.STOCK_ID
WHERE  
    A.BRANCH_ID = p_branchcode
    --AND STNK.NO_PENGAJUAN LIKE 
     --   TRIM (UPPER('%' || p_nopengajuan || '%'))
    --AND PENG.TANGGAL_PENGAJUAN >= p_datefrom
    --AND PENG.TANGGAL_PENGAJUAN <= p_dateto
  --  AND STOR.CHASIS_NO LIKE
    --    TRIM(UPPER('%' || p_chasisno || '%'))
    --AND STOR.ENGINE_NO LIKE
     --   TRIM(UPPER('%' || p_engineno || '%'))
    AND C.FIN_COMPANY_ID = '26'
    AND B.delivery_status = 'D'
    AND STNK.FAKTUR_PRINT_DATE IS  NULL
    AND STNK.FAKTUR_RECEIVE_DATE IS NULL
    AND STNK.PROCESS_DATE IS NULL
    AND A.ATTRIBUTE5 <> 0;
                 -- ORDER BY peng.TANGGAL_PENGAJUAN DESC;
   END;
```

And I call it from C# like this:

```
 public List<GetDataSTNK> GetDataCrossSelling(
      string kodeCabang, DateTime dariTgl, DateTime sampaiTgl, string biroJasa, string noPengajuan, string chasisNo, string engineNo)
    {
        List<GetDataSTNK> lst = new List<GetDataSTNK>();
        OracleParameter cursor = new OracleParameter("p_result", OracleType.Cursor);
        cursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        using (IDataReader reader = OracleHelper.ExecuteReader(
            connectionString,
            CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            "TRACKING_STNK.GetDataCrossSelling",
              new OracleParameter("p_branchcode", kodeCabang),
            new OracleParameter("p_datefrom", dariTgl),
            new OracleParameter("p_dateto", sampaiTgl),
            new OracleParameter("p_birojasa", biroJasa),
            new OracleParameter("p_nopengajuan", noPengajuan),
            new OracleParameter("p_chasisno", chasisNo),
            new OracleParameter("p_engineno", engineNo),
            cursor))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var r = new GetDataSTNK
                {
                    NoPengajuan = Convert.ToString(reader["NoPengajuan"]),
                    DONo = Convert.ToString(reader["DONo"]),
                    SPKNo = Convert.ToString(reader["STNKName"]),
                    CustomerName = Convert.ToString(reader["CustomerName"]),
                   //Amount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(reader["Flag_centang"].ToString())) ? (reader["Amount_DariIdent"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Amount_DariIdent"])) : (reader["Amount_DariCust"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Amount_DariCust"])),
                    AmountDetail = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["AmountDetail"].ToString()) ? Convert.ToDouble(reader["AmountDetail"]) : 0,
                    ProgressiveTax = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["ProgressiveTax"].ToString()) ? Convert.ToDecimal(reader["ProgressiveTax"]) : 0,
                    BiayaLainLain = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["BiayaLainLain"].ToString()) ? Convert.ToDecimal(reader["BiayaLainLain"]) : 0,
                    BPKBNo = Convert.ToString(reader["BPKBNo"]),
                    STNKNo = Convert.ToString(reader["STNKNo"]),
                    PoliceNo = Convert.ToString(reader["PoliceNo"]),
                    //ChasisNo = Convert.ToString(reader["CHASIS_NO"]),
                    //EngineNo = Convert.ToString(reader["ENGINE_NO"]),
                    StatusUpload = Convert.ToString(reader["StatusUpload"]),
                    Ket = Convert.ToString(reader["Ket"]),
                    TglUpload = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["TglUpload"].ToString()) ? Convert.ToDateTime(reader["TglUpload"]) : new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)
                };
                lst.Add(r);
            }
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

I get error:

> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 21:
> PLS-00302: component 'GETDATACROSSSELLING' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

What am I dong wrong?

Comment: This question is clearly about SQL and nothing to do with C# or ASP.NET. The application language and technology are irrelevant if using a different language and/or technology6 would not change the question at all. Please apply all relevant tags and no irrelevant ones. I have edited your tags on this occasion.

Comment: Having said that, maybe the C# code actually is relevant but you haven't included it. Maybe you should actually post the C# code you're using to execute this stored procedure. You would need to be creating a command object, setting the `CommandText` to the name of the procedure and the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`. If you're not doing that then that will be your issue. If you're going to tag your question C# then you should include the relevant C# code and an explanation of exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: this my c# code

Comment: halo, i update my post, i already post my c# code, can u help me please

Comment: Did you check that procedure compiled successfully? What is the definition of `data_cursor`?

Comment: The PL/SQL procedure has 2 parameters, but in C# you call a procedure with 8 parameters, this cannot work. I am quite sure the PL/SQL procedure does not compile.

Comment: Your procedure is in a package. Did you add the procedure declaration to the package specification, as well as the package body? If not it will be private and not visible to anyone else.

Comment: I think there is something about how you are declaring the Oracle procedure in .NET. This thing: new OracleParameter("p_branchcode", kodeCabang), new OracleParameter("p_datefrom", dariTgl), new OracleParameter("p_dateto", sampaiTgl),             new OracleParameter("p_birojasa", biroJasa)... Like the procedure would have more parameters than what it actually has. For in Oracle you only have the parameters p_branchcode and p_result. It looks like you are telling Oracle about a procedure with different parameters. Not sure how to use sys_refcursor in .NET

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have added your new procedure to the [package body](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-packages.html#GUID-49A935CE-825D-4FEA-BF2D-89F87EA9C750), but not to its [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-packages.html#GUID-85E86008-3460-4596-B43A-13D54D6E04C7). That means the procedure is private to the package - other procedures and functions within the same package can call it, but nothing outside can, including your C# code.

If you add the procedure declaration to the package specification as well, as

```
   PROCEDURE GetDataCrossSelling (
     p_branchcode    IN     MST_BRANCH.BRANCH_ID%TYPE,
     p_result           OUT DATA_CURSOR
   );
```

then the procedure will be public.

Your code will then get a different error, "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETDATACROSSSELLING'", because as pointed out in comments the procedure only has two parameters but you are supplying  8. You will then either need to change the call to only pass those two expected parameters, or (possibly, but maybe less likely as you don't seem to need them) modify the procedure declaration - in both the package specification and body - to expect all eight.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K421V9af) showing the two errors, with and without the procedure declared in the specification, and a successful call with two parameters - using an equivalent anonymous PL/SQL block in place of you C# code.